# SQL Developer Get Current Script Path

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm looking for a way to be able to select the path of a script inside the script.

For example, I create a script called test.sql. If I save this to C:\test\test.sql then running the select statement in the script would return C:\test\

Answer (score 0):

There's no way for server to know the client-side executed file path.

You have to code your way around this using your set of client-side tools.